# linux filesystem - what constitutes an inode?

Tags: linux, filesystems, inode

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I am confused by the concept of an inode.

Say I have a file.dat nested in a multi-level directory structure like this:

```
  folder_1 ->
     folder_2->
        folder_3->
          file.dat
```

How many inode(s) does this file take up in the filesystem?  Is it one (1 inode per file?) or 4 (including the folders?)

Comment: Seems more appropriate for unix.stackexchange.com, it's not a programming question.

Comment: Every directory itself has one inode and every file has one inode. There are links to file list in directory inode; and in file inode there are links to data of the file. `ls -li` shows you inode number for every element.

Answer (score 4):

Each directory is a special kind of file and has an inode of its own, and `file.dat` has its own inode. The inodes used by the directories are not generally counted when counting the inodes used by a file, since the same inodes are used for all the files in that directory. So if you add `file2.dat` to `folder_3`, it only uses up 1 more inode, not another 4.

Answer (score 0):

One.

Check out [Inode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) in wikipedia.

> A file's inode number can be found using the ls -i command. The ls -i command prints the i-node number in the first column of the report.